# How can I write a csv file and send it with nodemailer? with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, nodemailer

I want to write a csv file, and then email it with nodemailer as an attachment.
I have this code:

```
      const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
        path: 'out.csv',
        header: [
          {id: 'name', title: 'Name'},
          {id: 'desc', title: 'Description'},
          {id: 'image', title: 'Image'}
        ]
      });
      csvWriter
        .writeRecords(allAds)
        .then(()=> console.log('The CSV file was written successfully'));
```

how can I upload the file as an attachment to nodemailer?

Comment: By reading [Nodemailer's attachments documentation](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/) :)

Comment: try this out [How to send CSV files with Nodemailer](https://grizzlybit.info/blog/how-send-csv-files-with-nodemailer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, nodemailer supports different ways of setting [attachments](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/). So one way to do it is:

```
csvWriter
.writeRecords(allAds)
.then(() => {    
    let message = { 
        // ... message details   
        attachments: [{
                filename: 'csv-data.csv',
                path: '/path/to/out.csv' // stream this file
            }
        };
        // ... code for sending message
    });
```

One more thing - if you don't necessarily need to write the csv file to a file (and it's not too big) you can just use `createObjectCsvStringifier` from your [csv-library](https://github.com/ryu1kn/csv-writer) and use the resulting string. This will speed things up as you don't need to write/read from a file.